# MongoDart Authentication format issue

Tags: mongodb, dart

I'm trying to use MongoDart with Dart as backend. It was working fine till I shifted to a dedicated instance instead of serverless. This is the issue I see:

```
MongoDartError (MongoDart Error: Authentication failed.)
```

I'm using dedicated cluster with 3 nodes, deployment name is com-new and db name is main:

```
var db = await Db.create('mongodb+srv://com-admin:*****@com-new.iv00u.mongodb.net/main');
await db.open(); // MongoDart Error
```

This is working correctly on mongodb compass and mongoose, but on mongodart it gives the error auth failed. I also tried this:

```
mongodb+srv://com-admin:*****@com-new.iv00u.mongodb.net/main?authSource=admin
```

& this

```
mongodb+srv://com-admin:*****@com-new.iv00u.mongodb.net/main/?authSource=admin
```

This exact command is working with the old serverless db instance, but I want to use changeStreams which is not available unless we use a dedicated or shared cluster.

Comment: Are you sure the user has been created in `admin` database?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, since it is working on python, js and mongodb compass. I got in touch with the developer of the package. He said he might work on a fix but isn't sure if it is a mongodb issue or some syntax error on my end. Will update as soon as I get a solution

Comment: mongodb+srv:// scheme requires extra DNS steps.  Try using the mongod:// connection string from Atlas.